# SQL LIKE treating a PHP variable as a string

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am trying to search for a email with the same domain in a mysql database using using SQL `LIKE` as in

```php
$search=$_POST['searchTickets'];
$from=$_POST['fromm'];
$to=$_POST['too'];

$q=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mytickets WHERE email LIKE '%$search' AND dt BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ");
```

Although the `$search` have a string (example mydomain.com) that correspond to values found in mytickets table, email column (example name@mydomain.com), the mysqli_query keep returning zero results.

And somehow when I replace `email LIKE '%$search'` with `email LIKE '%mydomain.com'` it return the result I'm looking for. could it be sql is taking `$search` in `'%$search'` as a string? if so whats the right way to make SQL take it as PHP variable?

Comment: It looks like you want to directly build in send data into your SQL. This is an security vulnerability. More infos about SQL injection can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: It is possible that `$search` does not include the right value.

Comment: You right, `$search` was picking up the wrong value. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
$q=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mytickets WHERE email LIKE '%".$search."' AND dt BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ");
```

Comment: Still returning zero results, any other possible solution?

Comment: Is the rest of the condition ok? I suggest you add line
echo $q;
and check the statement, if it is ok. You can try to run it directly in phpmyadmin, or post it here.